# what is the meaning of that in C#? x ^ y

Tags: c#, .net

what is the meaning symbol **^** in **c#**?

> like example below.

```
if(x ^ y)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` is `XOR`.

In this case, can be written as:

```
if(x != y)
```

which may be easier to understand (if you are unfamiliar with the XOR operator)

Answer (score 1):

^ means XOR:

`x ^ y` is True if only `(x == true && y == false ) || (x == false && y == true)`.

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator)

Comment: I don't think your expression is correct. If both are false, `x^y` will return false. Your expression will return true due to right side of the `||`. I think you meant `(x == true && y == false ) || (x == false && y == true)`

Comment: @BrootsWaymb its the logic of Xor . if both are false, `(x== true && y== false)` would be false and also  `(x == false && y == true)` be false, and false || false would be false

Comment: Umm... what?? If both are false, `(x == false && y == false)` is obviously going to return true...

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I made a mistake in my comment (it was not what I wrote in my answer). I edited it. It is what we have studied in mathematics. I have studied pure mathematics ;)

Comment: That mistake also exists in your answer... Run your code with x and y both as false and tell me what you get... Because I get true when it should not for XOR.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb ohhhhh yes I had made a mistake in answer too. Thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: it was a really silly mistake